# Unable to get the Search results in List using Xpath or CssLocator in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

**Here is the requirement

1. Go to https://www.amazon.in/
2. Search for Apple Iphones
3. Get all Search results in to list
4. Iterate the list and print available iphone names and respective price.**

**Here i am able to do till step 2 and facing difficulty in in step 3. I.e i am unable to take the search results in the list. Any suggestions appreciated.**

This is the code i wrote

```
@Test
void test() {

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='nav-xshop']/a[.='Mobiles']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[5]//span[@class='a-size-small']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='Apple']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']"))
        .sendKeys("Apple iPhone");
    WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Go']"));
    searchButton.click();
    List<WebElement> searchResults = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//li[starts-with(@id='atfResults, 'result_')]"));
    for (WebElement searchResult : searchResults) {
        //Loop the List and Print name and price
    }
```

I have time constraint, Please help me to tackle this down. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your xpath is not correct ( the "." should not be there)

Try this xpath is for name:

```
//span[contains(@class, ' a-color-base a-text-normal')]
```

This one for price:

```
//span[@class='a-price-whole']
```

This is how you can take the price text based on name locator (parent to child)

```
 //span[contains(@class, ' a-color-base a-text-normal')]//following::span[@class='a-price-whole']
```

If you're trying to take all results in another way, store them as main div, if you iterate trough them and scrape the text for a specific child, you need to understand how locators are created.